# SWT: How to recreate a default context menu for text fields

Tags: java, swt, contextmenu

I need to add some items to the default context menu of a text control in SWT, but already found out I cannot modify this menu and have to create a new one from scratch.

But how do I emulate the default functions Undo, Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete? Do I really have to re-implement all this Clipboard stuff for myself? And I don't even know how to access the Undo history of the control. Is there some maybe dirty hack to emulate the key codes that achieve the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The `StyledText` has built-in support for Cut, Copy & Paste:

```
StyledText editor = new StyledText(...);
editor.invokeAction(ST.CUT);
editor.invokeAction(ST.COPY);
editor.invokeAction(ST.PASTE);
```

As for the Undo operation, I'm afraid you'll have to implement it yourself. `SWT` doesn't have anything useful here, AFAIK. Here's a good start if you want to do it yourself: [SWT Undo Redo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTUndoRedo.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I already found out that I can use the functions cut(), copy() and paste() on a Text control. Sadly, undo() is not available.

I now emulate undo by sending CTRL-Z (CTRL-Y on your US-Keyboard) to the app.