# How to add custom SWT context menu for Text box control

Tags: java, swt

I would like to modify the right click context menu for some some SWT Text boxes.

I would like to still have some of the default options like Copy, Cut, Paste, but would also like to have a custom action 'Generate Random' to fill the text box with a UUID.

How can I add such a menu to the control?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324633/how-can-we-add-menu-to-label-in-swt

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179464/swt-how-to-recreate-a-default-context-menu-for-text-fields).

Comment: thanks, that works for generating a new menu with custom actions, but how can I add some of the default actions like Copy, Paste back into the menu? Do I have to create my own custom versions for them or is there a way to use the default implementation?

Comment: The problem is that the default menu is created by the native control and varies a lot between platforms. On Mac OS X the menu has 11 top level items and many more in sub-menus. You can create your own Cut/Copy/Paste items for the menu but you would struggle with the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what I came up with to add some of the standard functions (cut, copy, paste, select all) as well as a custom action (generate UUID)

```
public static void addContextMenuWithUUID(final Text control)
{
    Menu menu = new Menu(control);
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("Cut");
    item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            control.cut();
        }
    });
    item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("Copy");
    item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            control.copy();
        }
    });
    item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("Paste");
    item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            control.paste();
        }
    });
    item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("Select All");
    item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            control.selectAll();
        }
    });
    item = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("Generate UUID");
    item.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            control.setText(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }
    });

   control.setMenu(menu); 
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. To add to this, I also attached a `MenuDetectListener` to the input Text `control` which sets the enabled state of "Cut" and "Copy" based on whether `control` has any text selected.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to do something similar a while ago, this is what I did,

I adopted the [TextActionHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.ui/ide/3.9.0/org/eclipse/ui/actions/TextActionHandler.java) class provided by eclipse and modified the code to suit my needs.

```
public final class TextActionHandler {

enum TextAction {

    CUT       (WorkbenchMessages.Workbench_cut, IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_CUT),
    COPY      (WorkbenchMessages.Workbench_copy, IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY),
    PASTE     (WorkbenchMessages.Workbench_paste, IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_PASTE),
    DELETE    (WorkbenchMessages.Workbench_delete, null),
    SELECT_ALL(WorkbenchMessages.Workbench_selectAll, WorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_SELECT_ALL);

    private String text;
    private String commandId;

    private TextAction(String text, String commandId ) {
        this.text       = text;
        this.commandId = commandId;
    }

    public String getCommandId() {
        return commandId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

public TextActionHandler(Text text) {
    addText(text);
}

public TextActionHandler() {
    super();
}

public void addText(Text textControl) {
    if (textControl == null) {
        return;
    }
    textControl.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            removeText(activeTextControl);
        }
    });
    textControl.addListener(SWT.Activate, textControlListener);
    textControl.addListener(SWT.Deactivate, textControlListener);

    textControl.addKeyListener(keyAdapter);
    textControl.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);

    activeTextControl = textControl;
    updateActionsEnableState();
}

public void hookContextMenu() {
    final MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PMPopupMenu");
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
            addContextMenuOptions(menuMgr);
        }
    });
    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(activeTextControl);
    activeTextControl.setMenu(menu);
}

private void addContextMenuOptions(MenuManager manager) {
    manager.removeAll();
    manager.add(textCutAction);
    manager.add(textCopyAction);
    manager.add(textPasteAction);
    manager.add(textDeleteAction);
    manager.add(new Separator());
    manager.add(textSelectAllAction);

    // add your own action handlers here
}

...

// example.
private final class CutActionHandler extends Action {

    private CutActionHandler() {
        setProperties(this, TextAction.CUT);
        setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void runWithEvent(Event event) {
        if (activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()) {
            activeTextControl.cut();
            updateActionsEnableState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return activeTextControl != null && !activeTextControl.isDisposed()
                && activeTextControl.getEditable()
                && activeTextControl.getSelectionCount() > 0;
    }

    public void updateEnabledState() {
        setEnabled(isEnabled());
    }
}

private void setProperties(Action action, TextAction actionEnum){

    action.setText(actionEnum.getText());
    action.setActionDefinitionId(actionEnum.getCommandId());
    action.setImageDescriptor(getImageDescriptor(actionEnum));
    action.setDisabledImageDescriptor(getDisabledImageDescriptor(actionEnum));

}
```

}

Likewise, you can have your own ActionHandlers added. e.g, RandomGeneratorHandler.
To hook this to your textboxes, do

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
...
TextActionHandler handler = new TextActionHandler();
handler.addText(text);
handler.hookContextMenu();
```

Note - I have not provided the complete class here, for other actions like copy, paste, delete and select all etc, you will have to do something similar as Cut. I have used the same code defined in the TextActionHandler class.